# Replace base character, retaining combining characters

Tags: regular-expression, unicode

I have a vocalized Hebrew text; most letters are followed by one or more combining characters.  I would like to replace some of the base characters, leaving the combining characters intact.  It seems the only way to search by base character alone is to use `\Z`, but when I include that in the search pattern, the combining characters are discarded in the substitution operation.  Also searching for the base char followed by a range of combining chars `\m\%ufb25[\u05b0-\u05bd]*` doesn't seem to work.

#### Example

ﬥְמַֽעַן וְהֽוּא־ﬥָֽךְ כְּסֶֽגֶן בְּאֶרְאֶﬥֵּי־אֵשׁ

This text has three occurrences of wide lamed (U+FB25) which I'd like to replace with regular lamed (U+05DC).  Each wide lamed is followed by different combining characters:

- <ﬥ‎> 64293, Hex fb25, Octal 175445 < ְ> 1456, Hex 05b0, Octal 2660
- <ﬥ‎> 64293, Hex fb25, Octal 175445 < ָ> 1464, ...5b8, Octal 2670 < ֽ> 1469, Hex 05bd, Octal 2675
- <ﬥ‎> 64293, Hex fb25, Octal 175445 < ֵ> 1461, ...5b5, Octal 2665 < ּ> 1468, Hex 05bc, Octal 2674

The ideal solution would yield the following with a single substitution:

לְמַֽעַן וְהֽוּא־לָֽךְ כְּסֶֽגֶן בְּאֶרְאֶלֵּי־אֵשׁ׃

Note: I avoided formatting as code blocks, because the difference between wide lamed and its regular counterpart isn't apparent when using a monospace font.  (Also it isn't really code, in the conventional sense.)

Comment: It was easy to solve with Python, which seems to view the text as just a sequence of code points, with no special treatment of combining characters.  It's good to know the strenths of each tool.

Answer (score 2):

This search pattern seems to work on your sample:

```
/\%ufb25\ze\(\%u05b0\|\%u05b8\|\%u05b5\)*\(\%u05bd\|\%u05bc\)*
```

That pattern will match every instance of `U+fb25`, optionally followed by `U+05b0`, `U+05b8`, or `U+05b5`, optionally followed by `U+05bd` or `U+05bc`. Only what precedes `\ze` is matched so the replacement only affects `U+fb25`, preserving the combining characters.

For the substitution part:

```
:s//\=nr2char(1500)/g
```

or simply:

```
:s//ל/g
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me.  Can you explain how/why it would work, and any settings or version dependencies?  According to the docs, `\ze` means "end of match."  It isn't obvious to me how that works in this context.  Also, can you explain the use of `\|` inside `[]`?  That construct is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: What doesn't work? This is pretty basic and should work in Vim without any setup (tested here with `$ vim -u NONE`).

Comment: I tried with vim -u NONE and it matches only wide lamed without any diacritics.  Except for `\ze` (which you explained), this looks pretty much the same as my failed attempt with `\%ufb25[\u05b0-\u05bd]*`.  I am using Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 11 2013 16:04:44).

Comment: Please see my edit and sorry for the brain fart. I stupidly used `[foo\|bar]` instead of `\(foo\|bar\)` where `\|` is used for alternation.

Comment: Maybe I should try with a newer version.

Comment: Your pattern works with a fresh compile of vim 8.0, but it is less practical, because it requires an explicit list of combining characters.  Can you fix my attempt to use `[]` instead, or explain why it doesn't work?  Specifying a range is preferred.